# ¿Cómo llamar a una url y almacenar sus resultados en un marco de datos de forma iterativa?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

Quiero recuperar el máximo de artículos desde una fecha determinada en un marco de datos. Es decir, en la siguiente forma:

```
            prices  articles
2007-01-01  12469   What Sticks from '06. Somalia Orders Islamist...
2007-01-02  12472   Heart Health: Vitamin Does Not Prevent Death ...
2007-01-03  12474   Google Answer to Filling Jobs Is an Algorithm...
2007-01-04  12480   Helping Make the Shift From Combat to Commerc...
2007-01-05  12398   Rise in Ethanol Raises Concerns About Corn as...
```

Puedo sacar 20 títulos del día. Creo que es el límite. Puse la fuente y el título en la columna e indique la fecha.

```
import requests

url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?'
       'language=en&'
       'from=2018-12-07&'
       'to=2018-12-07&'
       'sources=financial-times,australian-financial-review,reuters,the-times-of-india&'
       'apiKey=de9e19b7547e44c4983ad761c104278f')

response = requests.get(url)

import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

# using the pandas.io.json.json_normalize() function; 
# it can produce a dataframe for you from list-and-dictionaries structure typically loaded from a JSON source.
df = json_normalize(response.json(), 'articles')

# make the datetime column a native type, and add a date-only column
df['publishedAt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['publishedAt'])
df['date'] = df['publishedAt'].dt.date

# move source dictionary into separate columns rather than dictionaries
source_columns = df['source'].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('source_')
df = pd.concat([df.drop(['source'], axis=1), source_columns], axis=1)
```

Y obtengo con :

```
>>> pd.pivot_table(
...     df, index='date', columns='source_name', values='title',
...     aggfunc=list
... )

source_name Financial Times Reuters The Times of India
date            
2018-12-07  [Pound exodus: Brexit drives away US and Asia ...   [U.S. accuses Huawei CFO of Iran sanctions cov...   [Live 1st Test India vs Australia: Rain delays...
```

**¿Cómo obtener 20 resultados de estas fuentes indexadas cada día?
¿Cómo llamar a la url cada dias y almacenar sus resultados en un marco de datos de forma recursiva?**

#### El mio intento

```
dates = np.arange(np.datetime64('2018-12-09'), np.datetime64('2019-01-09'))

d = {'date'}
df = pd.DataFrame(index=d)

for date in dates:
    url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?'
       'language=en&'
       'from=%s&'
       'to=%s&'
       'sources=financial-times,australian-financial-review,reuters,the-times-of-india&'
       'apiKey=de9e19b7547e44c4983ad761c104278f')% (date,date)

    response = requests.get(url)
    # utilisando pandas.io.json.json_normalize(); 
    # puede producir un marco de datos para usted a partir de la estructura de listas y diccionarios que normalmente se carga desde una fuente JSON.
    df_new = json_normalize(response.json(), 'articles')

    # convierta la columna datetime en un tipo nativo y agregue una columna de solo fecha
    df_new['publishedAt'] = pd.to_datetime(df_new['publishedAt'])
    df_new['date'] = df_new['publishedAt'].dt.date

    # mueva el diccionario fuente a columnas separadas en lugar de diccionarios
    source_columns = df_new['source'].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('source_')
    df_new = pd.concat([df_new.drop(['source'], axis=1), source_columns], axis=1)
    df_new = pd.pivot_table(df_new, index='date', columns='source_name', values='title',aggfunc=list)
    # agregue el dataframe de la fecha dada al dataframe que los contiene a todos
    df.append(df_new, ignore_index=True)
```

Pero me da el siguiente:

```
date
```

Y eso es todo, como si nada hubiera pasado.

Answer (score 0):

La solución fue de `concat` las dataframes más bien que adjuntarla :

```
df_new = pd.pivot_table(df_new, index='date', columns='source_name', values='title',aggfunc=list)
# to add it to the dataframe
df = pd.concat([df_new,df])
```